nuance wording to state that two things are equivalent
Independent claim:
X is a positive number;

there are three other numbers: A, B, and C;

Y happens if A <= X, B <= X, and C <= X;

Dependent claim:
C is restricted to always equal zero.
In the specifications, the teachings state one of:

Omitting C can be interpreted as setting C to zero;
Omitting C can be interpreted to setting C to zero;
Omitting C is equivalent to setting C to zero;

Would there be any meaningful difference in choosing any one of the above statements over the other two?

Your example claim is not worded anything like a claim. If you get it in a claim form there might be a meaningful answer.

But I am only asking regarding the english grammar.

If you are trying to draft your own application and think the wording looks anything like claim wording I recommend you get a registered practitioner to help you.

If somehow the examples turned into the form of a claim I don’t see any difference in the effect of the three ways to word the specification.
